# Bug: time stamps in user profile page are wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I looked at my user profile and saw that a question is listed as having been posted 2 minutes ago, but when I clicked through to the question it said it had been posted 8 minutes ago.

Normally I wouldn't care about such a small discrepancy.  However, being a new user on MSO I'm limited to one question every 20 minutes.  Having entered MSO I'm in bug hunting mode, and I've already found 2 bugs, ported one from uservoice and written up a more general question.

It would be nice to have an accurate time stamp in the profile page so that I can see when I can post another question.

Comment: What page are you looking at? The one in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1084/nathan-fellman shows the timestamp of the last activity, while http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/1084 shows the timestamp of the last upvote.

Comment: I'm looking at the user profile page, not the recent activity page.

Answer (score 2):

The questions are cached to reduce the load, I'm pretty sure if you post exactly 20 minutes after your first post it will work, even if it isn't reported as such.

Comment: That is true.  It does work.  It's just annoying that that's the case

Comment: Find a large website that doesn't cache dates/timestamps and you have found a very rich company. Have you ever realized how long the view count on youtube videos are cached for?

Comment: I don't mind if this is closed with an erratum :-)  Just thought I'd bring it to the attention of the guys in charge.